# How can I switch the place of two keys in Windows 10?

Tags: remapping

Basically, I want the CapsLock key to become the Right Alt and the Right Alt to become the CapsLock. Is there a way to do this?

I tried Powertoys but it doesn't allow that. Also tried Scancode Map to no avail.

Comment: Might be able to use the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator? Not sure how or if it will handle the modifier keys though.

Answer (score 0):

**I will show you how to do this with AutoHotKey**

**Step 1** - Download and install [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)

**Step 2** - On your desktop, or in any directory, right click > new > autohotkey script

**Step 3** - Right click the autohotkey script and choose to edit with notepad

**Step 4** - Copy paste the following code into the notepad file:

```
; Swap Caps Lock with Right Alt
CapsLock::RAlt
RAlt::CapsLock
```

**Step 5** - Save/Exit notepad and double click the AutoHotKey script to start it. You know that it's running by observing a green 'H' icon that has now appeared in your task tray. You can right click that icon and stop the script from running if you choose.

**Additional steps if you want this to run every time you log into your computer:**

**Step 1** - Right Click your AutoHotKey.ahk script file and select "Compile". The script will now produce an EXE file in the same location.

**Step 2** - Copy the EXE file into your start-up folder location which is here:

```
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

**Step 3** - reboot and test. You should now find that the script automatically runs and swaps those keys each time you log into your user profile.